# Different Python paths on MacBook being used in Terminal and IDLE

Tags: python, macos, python-idle

I'm new to Python and have got myself into a muddle with Python versions on my MacBook.

Up until now I  have been tinkering around with Python on IDLE, but I  need to install a module (matplotlib) on the terminal.

The module installed fine via the terminal but seemed to have saved to a different version of Python to the version my IDLE uses. The module works directly on the terminal.
Basically I  can see by running sys.version + sys.path there are several files but how do I  choose which one to remove from my system and HOW do I remove the other files?

In the IDLE:

> > > import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >           import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
> > >       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'

When I  run sys in IDLE:

```
>>> sys.version
'3.8.2 (v3.8.2:7b3ab5921f, Feb 24 2020, 17:52:18) \n[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]'
>>> sys.path
['', '/Users/charlotteyandell/Documents', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python38.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
>>>
```

Back in the terminal, when I run the command 'which python', I  get back:
/Users/charlotteyandell/.pyenv/shims/python

When I  run sys.version:

```
>>> sys.version
'3.8.0 (default, Apr 14 2020, 11:01:35) \n[Clang 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.29)]'
>>> sys.path
['', '/Users/charlotteyandell/.pyenv/versions/3.8.0/lib/python38.zip', '/Users/charlotteyandell/.pyenv/versions/3.8.0/lib/python3.8', '/Users/charlotteyandell/.pyenv/versions/3.8.0/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/Users/charlotteyandell/.pyenv/versions/3.8.0/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
>>>
```

Comment: You're using pyenv, right?

Comment: I'm not using pyenv yet no, but reading about it, sounds like a smart idea

Comment: Oh, the only reason I asked is because of the `.pyenv` folder which appears in some of the file paths you shared above.

Comment: Right, looks like I  do have .pyenv installed yes.

Comment: Unfortunately I’m not very familiar with pyenv :/